# I want to draw a horizontal line

Tags: angular, chart.js, bar-chart

I want to draw a horizontal line  on my chart bar using chart js, I added the annotation element to the chart options but it doesn't work.

```
annotation: {
      annotations: [{
        type: 'line',
        mode: 'horizontal',
        scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
        value: 5,
        borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
        borderWidth: 4,
        label: {
          enabled: false,
          content: 'Test label'
        }
      }]
    }

annotation: {
      annotations: [{
        type: 'line',
        mode: 'horizontal',
        scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
        value: 5,
        borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
        borderWidth: 4,
        label: {
          enabled: false,
          content: 'Test label'
        }
      }]
    }
```

I want to draw a horizontal line on my bar chart js.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine when I test it. Do you import the plugin correctly, something like 
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/0.5.7/chartjs-plugin-annotation.min.js"></script>` ?

[Here is my test-jsbin](https://jsbin.com/tagomonili/1/edit?html,js,output) where it works exactly like it's supposed to with your code (I only changed the value).